# Android Studio Exif Tag Editing for "ProjectionType" and "UsePanoramaViewer" Tags

Tags: android, exif

Quick question, does anyone know how to read/write exif tags that aren't a part of the ExifInterface class. The ones I am looking to override are "ProjectionType" and "UsePanoramaViewer". They both are not listed in the [ExifInterface documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface).

Is there a way to access them with this library, or should I look elsewhere? Thanks for the help!

Comment: ExifInterface doesn't support writing exif to images. You need to use Apache Commons/Imaging to write.

Comment: @AIMINPAN - `saveAttributes()` absolutely writes all Exif changes (done via `setAttribute()`) to the file.